# Force light mode on single View

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I have an Android app which supports night mode by inheriting the theme from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`. This works perfectly fine.

However, for a specific View, I want to force light mode at all times. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no - I'm now setting specific colors with no night variants on those elements. A bit cumbersome, but it works.